# missing the first character of each line on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server terminal

Tags: ubuntu-server, ubuntu-20.04

I see the first character of each line missing on the on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server terminal. As shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9M9U.jpg)

How to fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an analog (VGA) video connection, and the LCD monitor failed to correctly guess where the visible part of the video signal begins.

Open a full-screen program which has a background color other than black (such as Vim with `:color blue`) then press the monitor's "Auto-adjust" button.

Answer (score 1):

That's purely a hardware problem. Your CRT display's electron beam is misaligned in relation to the input signal. An analoguous effect can be observed on LCD screens when the VGA connection is used.

You have to use monitor's menu to align the display.